# .net MVC deploying on IIS7 Express : Read in embedded resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

My MVC .net Solution has 2 projects:

1. The actual web project

   This is all my models, views, controllers, attributes, etc.  Some of the controllers reference my Reporting project, which includes local (e.g. non-server reports) reports that use SSRS and PDF generation.
2. The Reporting Project

   This includes code that will connect to a database and generate the reports.  The project also includes a folder that has a bunch of report templates.  The report templates are "embedded resources".  I have confirmed that they show up in the bin folder of the MVC app when I deploy.

The problem is, when I call the reporting code from within a controller, IIS looks for the report file relative to IIS.  In the report code, I might say to look at "report/confirmation.rdlc".  This works fine in a console app, however once I deploy with IIS, that path ends up being "C:/program files(x86)/iis express/reports/confirmation.rdlc", which does not exist.

I have also tried "~/report/confirmation.rdlc" to the same result.

I am assuming this means that the home folder (~) is in fact the IIS Express root.  How can I change that for the app?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `Server.MapPath("~/bin/reports/confirmation.rdlc")` instead.